# Kindle doesn't show cover

Tags: kindle, calibre, kindle-paperwhite, file-format

I just got a kindle as Christmas present. I got myself [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) and loaded 4 E-Books on my kindle. I can open and read every book, but unfortunately I just can see the covers of 2 of these 4 E-Books although I set them explicitly with calibre. Does anyone of you know the cause for this failure?

**Edit** I figured out that I couldn't see any covers because they had pdf format. I converted them to mobi and then it worked. But is it still possible to see a cover for pdf books? Because when I convert my pdf's to mobi the formatting is completely messed up. Or do you have any suggestions for proper formatting tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PDF file format does not support cover images.

PDF was designed to show a faithful representation of printed pages.
Reflowing text to other page sizes typically is not possible; you should use PDF on an ebook reader only when the page layout is important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to format pdf to kindle properly? I have no appropriate sections anymore and newlines are random too. It's not good to read then tbh

Comment: Reformatting PDFs is not possible in the general case.

Comment: Whilst this may be true in theory, there are plenty of pdfs out there with full page cover images. If you convert an ebook with a cover image to PDF with calibre, it's first page will be the cover image.

Comment: It's no longer true that you can't reformat PDF's (if it ever was). When you go to move the PDF onto the Kindle you will be asked if you'd like to convert it to a Kindle book. The PDF layout will be converted to whatever Kindle thinks it should be -- and that might not necessarily be a good thing.